# Spring caffeine cache using size

Tags: spring-boot, caffeine-cache

So I have set up my spring boot service with caffeine cache.
The service is deployed in a k8 cluster with a memory of 4Gi.

Now i want to store almost 300000 items in the inmemory cache, would this be doable using caffeine cache? Or maybe i should look at redis cache for this?

```
spring.cache.caffeine.spec=maximumSize=300000
```

Comment: it would depend on the memory usage per entry, the memory required by other work on the server, etc. it can be helpful to measure, e.g. stats or gc behavior, to make educated guesses. unfortunately this question is too open ended to give a concrete answer.

Comment: generate 1000 entries in your cache locally, see how much memory consumption increased because of it with a profiler (e.g. Visual VM), then multiply that number by 300 and see if that number is under 2-3 GB. If yes then 4GB should be sufficient, otherwise adjust accordingly